# IF statement for Distance - Flow

Tags: visual-workflow, formula, compile-error

I am trying to create a screen flow without using a loop to display "Nearby Accounts" (within 10 miles). However I am getting an error as seen in the below screenshot. I am fairly new to using formulas in flow so any help would be much appreciated.

Here is the screen shot of the formula in a Collection Filter:
[image]

Formula:
IF(DISTANCE(
GEOLOCATION({!recordId.BillingLatitude} ,
{!recordId.BillingLongitude}),
GEOLOCATION({!currentItem_Collect_Accounts_WIthin_10_miles.BillingLatitude}, {!currentItem_Collect_Accounts_WIthin_10_miles.BillingLongitude}),
'mi') <10)

Here is an overview of my flow:
[image]

For context I am not using a loop because our org has too many accounts as when implementing a loop the number of iterations are exceeded.

What I want the formula in the collection filter to achieve is to return Accounts that are within 10 miles of an Account.

Comment: Please [edit] your post to include the error text and show the details of what the step is doing.

Comment: @DavidCheng sorry about this I forgot to add the screenshot of the formula. I hope this makes sense.

Comment: If `DISTANCE` and `GEOLOCATION` are permitted in a formula, you need to make sure the `IF` has the three parameters. So here something like `IF(DISTANCE(...) < 10, TRUE, FALSE)`

Comment: I must say, it's annoying you cannot do a `DISTANCE` calculation/filter in the `Get Records` element itself.

Comment: Hi guys, I have managed to get this working! @PhilW thank you. I have achieved it by using the following formula in the Collection Filter: IF(DISTANCE(
      GEOLOCATION({!recordId.BillingLatitude} , 
      {!recordId.BillingLongitude}),
      GEOLOCATION({!currentItem_Collect_Accounts_WIthin_5_miles.BillingLatitude}, {!currentItem_Collect_Accounts_WIthin_5_miles.BillingLongitude}),
  'mi') <5, TRUE, FALSE)

Answer (score 0):

The `IF` function always takes three parameters. You need to update your `IF` so it has the condition **and** the two resulting values. Since you are only interested in whether the condition is met (or not) you need to make it something like:

```
IF(DISTANCE(...) < 10, TRUE, FALSE)
```

I have left out the detail passed to the `DISTANCE` function for clarity.

This says, if the condition (here the check for distance) is met then return `TRUE` otherwise return `FALSE`.